# An enumerated list and a picture side by side

Tags: sidebyside

I'd like to have an enumerated list and a picture side by side. I could use the feature with beamer using columns environment, but I need the similar feature outside beamer.

```
\begin{columns}%
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}%
\begin{center}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{pic/}
\end{center}%
\end{column}%
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}%
    ... % enum
\end{column}%
\end{columns}%
```

I tried to use two minipages to put side by side, but my code doesn't work. What might be the solution?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\boxit}[1]{\fbox{\begin{minipage}{#1}\hfill\vspace{1em}\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}\centering
    \includegraphics[width=2.5in]{gg} 
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}\centering

\begin{enumerate}[label = \arabic*.]
\setlength\itemsep{-0.2em}
\addtocounter{enumi}{0}
\item \boxit{3in} 

\item \boxit{3in}
\item \boxit{3in}
\item \boxit{3in}
\item \boxit{3in}
\item \boxit{3in}
\item \boxit{3in}
\item \boxit{3in}
\item \boxit{3in}
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By removing the line gap between the minipages, i can get them side by side, if that is what you were after.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\boxit}[1]{\fbox{\begin{minipage}{#1}\hfill\vspace{1em}\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}\centering
    \rule{2cm}{2cm} % <--- to get a filler on my build.
\end{minipage}%<-- no line gap between minipages
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}\centering
\begin{enumerate}[label = \arabic*.]
\setlength\itemsep{-0.2em}
\addtocounter{enumi}{0}
\item \boxit{3in} 

\item \boxit{3in}
\item \boxit{3in}
\item \boxit{3in}
\item \boxit{3in}
\item \boxit{3in}
\item \boxit{3in}
\item \boxit{3in}
\item \boxit{3in}
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]